# Plot two-dimensional array as elliptical orbit

Tags: matlab, ellipse

I am attempting to plot an elliptical orbit based on a 2-D position array, beginning at `p= [5 0]`. The plot charts positions from a timeframe `t`, here between 0 and 100. The calculation uses the formula F = -(p/||p||)(m*M/(p^2) to approximate acceleration and velocity. The result should look like the following:
[image]

This is my current code. It plots a completely different shape. Is the problem in my way of interpreting the force equation?

Any other help and comments are much appreciated.

```
t = 0; p = [50 0]; v = [0 8]; %Initial conditions
dt = 0.05;
M = 10000; m= 1;
tmax = 100;
figure, hold on
d = 0.001
clf;
while t < tmax
        F = -(p./norm(p)).*(m*M./(p*p'));
        a = F./m - d*v;
        v = v + a*dt;
        p = p + v*dt;
        t = t + dt;
        
        plot(p(1),t,'o','MarkerSize',0.5);
        hold on;
        plot(p(2),t,'o','MarkerSize',0.5);
end
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is not just the initial conditions being different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `p(1)` in the *x* axis and `p(2)` in the *y* axis, with `t` as a parameter. So you need to replace the two `plot` lines by `plot(p(1),p(2),'o','MarkerSize',0.5);` (keeping `hold on`):

```
t = 0; p = [50 0]; v = [0 8]; %Initial conditions
dt = 0.05;
M = 10000; m= 1;
tmax = 100;
figure, hold on
d = 0.001
clf;
while t < tmax
        F = -(p./norm(p)).*(m*M./(p*p'));
        a = F./m - d*v;
        v = v + a*dt;
        p = p + v*dt;
        t = t + dt;
        hold on
        plot(p(1),p(2),'o','MarkerSize',0.5); %%% modified line
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't realize ```t``` was not on the x-axis.